# Android ant run-tests artifacts

Tags: android

When I do an ant run-tests on my android test project it runs fine and I can see a summary of tests run and failures. Is there more detailed information available, like a log file I can save on each test run? Basically I want to be able to run my tests from the command line and for each run have a list of failures/passes with as much detail as possible plus a capture from logcat (but I guess I have to do that manually).
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at Android JUnit Report Test Runner:

https://github.com/jsankey/android-junit-report

Comment: But this requires me to change my test apk. I would like to avoid this if possible. Eclipse can figure it out without any changes.